# As a two-dimensional array receive from an ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

Through an Ajax, I'm doing a query that returns me an array with two positions to create a pick list created with javascript. In the first value that has the value and the second has the name (The name and value are the same).

This is the answer of my ajax:

```
var valores = new Array();
var nombres = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < respuesta.length ; i++)
 {
  valores[i] = respuesta[i]["COLUMN_NAME"];
  nombres[i] = respuesta[i]["COLUMN_NAME"];
 }
 documentopropiedades.opciones[3] = [valores,nombres];
```

Being documento.propiedades [3] the place where the list.

When I go to create the form everything goes normal full list like this:

```
var valorCampo =  Array();
var nombreCampo =  Array();
campotabla = [valorCampo,nombreCampo];
```

And it brings me the data but when I go to edit me not load form the data I have already recorded in the database on this select, tried running again ajax within the document.ready but I can not get me to load data the select

Comment: Hard to understand what you want to. Do you want to deliver a multi-dimensonal array to your ajax call?

Comment: I want to know how from a document.ready I can call the function that executes the ajax and get that two-dimensional array that this returns me

Comment: Javascript does not support multi-dimensional arrays but it DOES  support arrays of arrays.  I think that you have to proceed from that.

Comment: Why Javascript does not support multi-dimensional arrays? It does!

Comment: @DOCTYPE HTML: What proof can you offer that JavaScript supports multidimensional arrays?  An array that contains an array is not the same thing.

Comment: Ofcourse it is. What should it be else? An Array which holds an array is a multidimensional Array.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recieve arrays by a ajax call. So you just encode it in php and decode in javascript!

In PHP:

> echo json_encode($multi_dimensonal_array);

In your ajax request:

> multi_dimensonal_array = JSON.parse(multi_dimensonal_array);

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_array.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data: send}
}).done(function(multi_dimensonal_array){
    multi_dimensonal_array = JSON.parse(multi_dimensonal_array);
    console.log(multi_dimensonal_array[0]);
    console.log(multi_dimensonal_array[1]);
});
```

Comment: But as I do for the array in the function call within the document.ready? 
I'm trying this and I have not gotten: 
$(document).ready(function(){
var v = consultarCampos(document.getElementById('SistemaInformacion_idSistemaInformacion').value, tabla); 
          alert(v);  
});
In the alert I get undefined :(

Comment: Where did you get your multi-dimensional array? By an ajax call, or not? So when you get them via json_encoded ´echo´ you just decode it back in Javascript and store in a variable.